# readline() in Jupyter IRKernel

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I'm currently working to transfer some R scripts of mine into a Jupyter notebook in order to make them more accessible; however, I'm running into the issue that `readline()` is returning `""`, the default in non-interactive use. Jupyter (frustratingly so) seems to be non-interactive (i.e., `interactive()` returns `FALSE`).

Are there any known workarounds (other than a clunky interface) for the people who might use this Notebook? 
I had previously used `readline()` to enter data using a loop line-by-line into a dataframe built off a MySQL query in which the size may be variable. It's hard to preëmpt what size it might be, so being able to enter using `readline()` was particularly useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

April status: People thought about R-jupyter readline since 2015 and then finally finished implementing and merging interactive input just a few days ago. See https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/199 and https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/pull/452.  This is in master, but no released version.