# Force R to show plot before input in Colab

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, jupyter-irkernel

I'd like to display a plot and *then* have the user give some input, but the plot always appears *after* the input line.  A simple example is:

```
plot( 1:10 )
ans <- readline("What is your favorite number?")
```

which gives the prompt first and *then* does the plot.  The end goal will then be to do this in a `for` loop, where each iteration I present a plot and then ask the user for feedback about the plot.

This is in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/#create=true&language=r) and I'd like to stay working in Colab as this is an application for students and I want something they can run easily.

I've tried various things including `Sys.sleep(0)` and `flush.console()` but without any luck.

**Edit** My MWE above isn't actually representative of my code. A better example is the following:

```r
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)
print('Hello')
```

Comment: The problem here seems to be that the colab R-sessions aren't [interactive()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/interactive):

`An interactive R session is one in which it is assumed that there is a human operator to interact with, so for example R can prompt for corrections to incorrect input or ask what to do next or if it is OK to move to the next plot.` Otherwise you could have used `par(ask=TRUE)` / `devAskNewPage(ask=TRUE)` Personally I'd create a `shiny` app in this situation.

Comment: Any reason you cant put `readline` in the next code chunk?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/236) you can find a relevant GitHub issue (open since 2015) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43549018/9841389) a related SO post.

Comment: Thanks for the info @ismirsehregal.  `shiny` would be nice but would take some time to get up to speed on and I need to host (this is for a class I teach, so with many users, I am not sure the free hosting works).  @nniloc, from my MWE that seems reasonable, but really this is in a loop (the user is playing a game), so it wouldn't work

Comment: @Stephen RStudio has a [Academic Pricing Policy](https://www.rstudio.com/pricing/academic-pricing/). Maybe that's something to look at on the long run. E.g. check the shiny wizard example [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#dynamic-wizard) or library([learnr](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/)).

Comment: @Stephen I just came across [webR](https://github.com/georgestagg/webR) they provide an `interactive()` REPL [here](https://webr.gwstagg.co.uk/).

Answer (score 3):

you could use `plot.new()`:

> This function (frame is an alias for plot.new) causes the completion of plotting in the current plot

```
plot( 1:10 )
plot.new()
ans <- readline("What is your favorite number?")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works for the MWE I posted, though it turns out that the MWE isn't representative of my problem because I use `par` and apparently that changes things.  A better MWE is

``` lang-r
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    par(mfrow=c(1,2))
    plot(1:10)
    plot(1:10)
    print('Hello')
```

  Now, adding the `plot.new()` after the plotting and before the printing does not have any effect.

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty because this solves the original MWE I posted (though not the actual problem I had in mind)

Comment: @Stephen, thanks, I tried to find a workaround with `par` but unfortunately didn't succeed ;-)